# why does《Java Virtual Machine Specification》 describe Java Virtual Machine architecture

Tags: jvm, specifications

In my cognition，A specification should not care about internal implementation,it just need define interfaces. If a specification described using architecture, it is difficult to judge whether an implementation meets this specification.

Comment: Where does JVMS describe the implementation?

Comment: A well defined interface has documented expected behavior. The description of a complex behavior may use an abstract architecture as a tool. For example, C++ uses an abstract machine to specify behavior, despite such machine does not exist. Don’t get confused by the fact that there is software literally implementing a Java Virtual Machine. I suggest reading §1.2 carefully. The specification does not describe an actual implementation (aside from informal examples).